# Prove $n \times 1$ vectors Linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$-matrix. Three column vectors $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are given, and we have that $$A^2X_1=A^2X_2=A^2X_3=0$$ We know that $AX_1,AX_2, AX_3$ are linearly independent. Prove that the column vectors $X_1,X_2,X_3,AX_1,AX_2,AX_3$ are also linearly independent.

It is a hard problem for me, and my first thought was that $A^2X_1=0 \Rightarrow AX_1=0$. That is probably not correct and not leading to anything.

I then concluded that $\det(AX_1,AX_2, AX_3)\not=0$ which can lead me somewhere, since it's a proof with linear independence and $\det\not=0 \Leftrightarrow$ *lin. independent*.

Comment: It is spelled 'prove'.

Comment: You definitely have $n\geq6$ (if what you want to prove is to be true) but $\det(AX_1,AX_2,AX_3)$ only makes sense if $n=3$. So that is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: The problem doe not say anything about $n \ge 6$, why must that be the case?

Comment: If the dimension would be less than$~6$, how can you expect to prove that six vectors are linearly independent? They would never be. However the main point of my remark is that by writing down a determinant _you_ are making an assumption about the dimension, which as you rightly say the question says nothing about. You can _only_ use determinants is the number of vectors is exactly equal to the dimension (determinants are defined for _square_ matrices only).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write down the general form of a linear relation between those $6$ vectors. Assuming you have such a relation, apply $A$ to it. Using the given linear independence, conclude that three of the coefficients must be$~0$. Then look at your original linear relation in the light of this new information, and conclude that the remaining three coefficients must also be$~0$. Conclude.